# Do I start in a mission

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just got GTA V toady and I was wondering if when i start a new game do I spawn in a mission like in GTA 4? If so can I skip it or something? Because I hate the GTA campaign.

Comment: Are you asking how to skip the entirety of the single player content?

Comment: I just want to know if right when I start the game after it loads if it automatically puts me in a mission and if I can quit the mission and go into free roam.

Comment: You do start in a mission. Its not that bad, its pretty good.

Comment: so you just got GTA V and instead of trying it you just ask question? My suggestion: do not install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GTA V your first occuance in the game's introduction is a prologue(backstory) to two of the characters(Michael & Trevor). Then continues onto Franklin's introduction(Stealing and driving cars).
After completing these, free roam is available. You must complete up to Franklin in order to have a current save game, for those only wanting multiplayer, you cannot start multiplayer until you have a save(prologue completed) where after that you can go straight into multiplayer after 5 seconds into the prologue.